# presenting multi column table in a table view

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I am trying to present a a table with 6 columns (name, City, phone #, sex, State, device Type) in a table view for iPad.

I display them using a custom cell[image]

The above layout shows the information. But it does not seem appealing to me. Is there any better way to display the information in the cell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these sites, so you can get some ideas of what you can do:

http://mobile-patterns.com/lists

http://pttrns.com/lists

Hope it helps.